# How to display debug output from android logcat in NetBeans?

Tags: java, android, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I am using *jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0* in NetBeans by Gluon.
After launch debug apk I want display debug output from Android logcat in NetBeans Output console, but I don't known how it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for NetBeans, nbandroid. It has recently been updated to the 8.1 version.

You can install it following this [link](https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid/wiki/Installation): on NetBeans->Tools->Plugins, select settings tab, add this new URL: http://nbandroid.org/release81/updates/updates.xml. Then on the available plugins look for Android, and install both Android and Android Gradle Support plugins.

Before you can use it, edit NetBeans->Tools->Options->Miscellaneous, Android tab, and make sure the Android SDK path is provided.

Then you will be able to use it, by calling NetBeans->Windows->Output->ADB Log.

Comment: If that works for you, accept the answer so it can be useful for others as well.

Comment: Making problems when adding imports from Source Packages folder to classes in Android/Java Packages folder.

Comment: Making problems when adding imports from Source Packages folder to classes in Android/Java Packages folder. So that it blocks rational utilization project - I had to deactivate Android plugin and Android Gradle Support plugin - probably any problem with Gradle/Gradles.

Comment: It seems it is a reported [issue](https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid/issues/73/editor-flags-oncreateoptionsmenu). I typically prefer the terminal and `adb logcat`, or Android/sdk/tools/Monitor, if you want a GUI.